# What is the role of HibernateUtil?

Tags: java, hibernate

I'm new to Hibernate, and everytime I come across a Hibernate tutorial there is a mention of HibernateUtil class ?

What actually does it do ? And if there is a standard implementation why don't it being included in Hibernate jar itself?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There's an answer [here](http://www.coderanch.com/t/218738/ORM/java/HibernateUtil) that might suffice.

Looks like they want developers to write their own by design, because the number of possibilities to cover is too large.

Comment: Isn't it more like that HibernateUtils is a singleton which is an anti-pattern?